# How to sort a Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I am using crystal report add-on on my visual studio 2015. I have a problem, I have access database with table looks like in images:

[image: looks like in this images]

I want to sort my database with field tanggal_pembayaran as parameters, using group selection in selection formula on crystal report but here is what the formula looks like:

[image: here the formula looks like]

I don't know which formula to use to make it like that parameter becomes the initial limit for the report date to display data with date above the entered date which i don't know how.

Comment: Can you be clear..do you want the report to be sorted based on parameter?

Comment: yes i want tanggal_pembayaran  to be sorted as parameter

Comment: sort or filter..do you want it in where or just arrange on order?

Answer (score 0):

To Filter and Sort by a Parameter field in crystal report

1. create a parameter Field
    right click the parameter field in field explorer and add new
    give name and datataype (here datetime)
2. to filter data using parameter field

   Go to Reports>>Selection Formula>>Records   and provide formula
     here it will be like
    {Customers.CreationDate}<{?Creationdate}  save and close
3. to Sort data using parameter

   Go to Report >> Record Sort Expert>>From report field add the Parameter field.If not visiable add the field first to the report then it will be visibale

Comment: i know that, emm is hard to exmplain hahaha